# BGE: when testing the game the screen glitches

Tags: game-engine

I am making a game in which I am giving controls to a car. I am using the Blender game engine. [image: THIS IS THE GLITCH SCREEN]The problem is that when I play the game to see how it works the screen glitches. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I have had this issue in the past. Try changing from GLSL mode to multitexture mode. Try resizing the window so it isn't full screen. Try running the game engine in "standalone" rather than "embedded." Also, make sure you have up to date graphics drivers.